# How can I make Gwibber use Desktop Couch?

Tags: 10.10, ubuntu-one, sync, gwibber, desktopcouch

I want to make use UbuntuOne to sync my data. I saw that Gwibber can use DesktopCouch to sync accounts, messages and preferences, but Gwibber stores all data in a SQLite file. The databases in my CouchDB are empty.

How can I start Gwibber to make use of CouchDB?

Answer (score 3):

Gwibber no longer uses couchdb as it's backend. It is no longer possible to make it sync across computers.

Comment: buhuu, why? Can I sync the .gwibber folder?

Comment: You sure can  :)

Comment: Be warned: gwibber might not like having its folder synced. We'd be interested to hear if this works, but be prepared for it to not work -- gwibber probably isn't prepared for its own database changing while it's running, for example! Keep backups.